# How do you phrase “due to strong winds” in German

Tags: english-to-german

I’ve seen different forms written in articles:

1. > Wegen starken Winden
2. > Wegen starken Windes
3. > Wegen starke Winde
4. > Wegen zu starken

I’m confused honestly. I haven’t fully grasped the concept of *Genetiv* case yet. Also I heard from people around and also the comments below that *Dativ* is also used with *wegen*, but I should try to avoid it in writing or formal speech, right?

Adding the context: I wanted to make a sentence to express, “Due to the strong winds, the gondola is not in service today / Due to the strong winds, the gondola is not running today.”

Comment: "Wegen starken Winden" would be correct, if "Wind" was countable. In german, it is not (apart from very rare philosophical cases).

Comment: Here, as so often, a useful answer would need a question where context is given. Where do these strong winds occur, and what do they cause? Are they concrete winds (as atmospheric phonomena), or are they winds in some metaphorical way?

Comment: @PMF: sorry, but I disagree about the "wind is not countable in German"- theory. Especially in meteorology there for sure is the plural form of "Wind" as "die Winde". When talking about planes e.g. you will often hear "Fallwinde" and in the context of sailing it is also very common usage. Often you then talk about special winds like "der Passat- Wind" or the like, but this is not necessarily true.

Comment: @TorstenLink  Also in medicine, *Winde* (plural of *Wind*) is used for certain bodily expressions. This would be another field where the phrase *wegen starker Winde* could occur.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: You are absolutely right. That association made me smile...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Hello, I’m sorry I wasn’t clear about the context, I wanted to make a sentence to say, “Due to the strong winds, the gondola is not in service today.” Thanks everyone for their input!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann thanks for sharing this! I learnt something new today :)

Comment: @T.doublenine  *Winde* in the medical sense is about the same register of speech as *Stuhl* for the more tangible outcomes of said opening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Wegen* is a preposition that commonly takes the Genitive in German. Grammatically correct is thus the following:

> - Wegen starker Winde
> - Wegen starken Windes

There is an exception that allows to use strongly flexed stand-alone substantives without article and attribute in their non-flexed form (thus in nominative):

> - Wegen Wind

(Commonly seen on road-signs, for example)

There is another exception that allows using the dative in case the genitive is not detectable (has the same form as another case) or the sentence already has another attribute in genitive:

> - wegen Geschäften
> - Wegen meiner Eltern neuem Haus (*I have yet to hear anybody saying that, but It is correct*)

Other usage with the dative is relatively common, but, strictly speaking, wrong or rather colloquial. This is very commonly used and accepted in regions where the local dialect doesn't know the genitive (mainly in the South):

> - <s>wegen dem schlechten Wetter</s> (correct: "wegen schlechten Wetters")
> - <s>wegen meinen schlechten Noten</s> (correct: "wegen meiner schlechten Noten")

Comment: "Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod". My observation seems to imply that "accepted […] mainly in the South" is no longer true. It's now everywhere?

Comment: @LangLangC You need to distinguish between the various cases / reasons for genitive, I think. Possessive usage declines in my experience, but the specific case of *wegen* seems to be strong with genitive, at least in the media.

Answer (score 2):

The words "due to" also have other possible translations into German, not just *wegen*. Some of these constructs seem to flow easier than those with *wegen*:

- aufgrund – starker Winde, starken Windes, (starkem Wind)
- dank  – starker Winde, starkem Wind, starken Windes
- [bedingt] durch – starke Winde, starken Wind
- infolge – starken Windes, (starkem Wind), starker winde
- ob – starken Windes (excellent choice, but antiquated and therefore eyebrow raising)

Expressions in brackets are seen in the wild, and understood broadly, but not really nice style, considered between something like incorrect, awkward, or sometimes just the usual idiosyncrasy (of class, age, region, dialect).

Comment: I’m aware that there are also other possible ways to express “due to”, I just wanted to focus on wegen. And also I provided the context to make it easier to discuss. But thank you for your answer! I’m still learning German, I’m happy to learn about other expressions!

Answer (score 0):

*Wegen* allows usage of *Dativ* and *Genitiv* cases. Not so long ago usage of *Dativ* was considered incorrect. It was frowned upon in written language and among more educated people. However, Dativ became so common that the *Duden* had to accept it as equally valid.

Thus, you can use both Genitiv and Dativ. You may also use both singular and plural.

- wegen starken Windes (Gen. singular)
- wegen starker Winde (Gen. plural)
- wegen starkem Wind (Dat. singular)
- wegen starken Winden (Dat. plural) [IMHO, this option sounds somewhat strange.]

Note: *Duden* states that usage with *Dativ* is *umgangssprachlich* or in certain cases *standardsprachlich*. If you use *Genitiv* in an exam or scientific article, you can still face problems. Which form to use depends on your target audience. The safer choice is *Genitiv*. On the other hand, in a beer hall speech a politician would try to avoid the *Genitiv* to demonstrate closeness to the people.

Comment: That is not entirely correct. The Duden accepts Dativ only in [colloquial speech](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wegen_infolge_bezueglich).

Comment: @IQV yes I agree that the Dativ case for wegen is only used in colloquial speech, my German teacher once mentioned this too.

Comment: @IQV: You're right that my answer is not generally right. However, it's not only colloquial usage. The Duden states that *Dativ* is *standardsprachlich* (!= *umgangssprachlich*) correct (with some further restrictions). This would probably disqualify its usage in a dissertation, but not in a normal newspaper.

Comment: @IQV The Duden does not _accept_ anything, it only _describes_ how people do something.

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt You want to go back to the Duden and read again. Duden states *Umgangssprachlich mit Dativ* (generally) and *standardsprachlich mit Dativ **in bestimmten Fällen***.

Comment: If you want to avoid debates about how acceptable *wegen* plus dative is, use *aufgrund*, which only allows the genitive.